# Cost / Configuration of AzureNotificationHubs with >1 Firebase App / >1 iOS App

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

I have an Azure Notification Hub (ANH) configured with a Google Firebase Cloud Messaging application.  Our application back end will need to also push notifications to a second Google Firebase Cloud Messaging application.  That is the 2 Android applications will have different API Key values.  Later we will wish to do the same for iOS -- push notifications to 2 separate iOS applications from our 1 back-end.

Will the Standard tier allow us to use these 4 applications from one Notification Hub?  How does the Multi-Tenancy feature map into this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

The hub concept is built around apps. This means one hub maps to one app no matter the circumstance. The one app can be cross-platform, so you can have an iOS version of the app, an Android version, etc. Each hub is designed to have one certificate enabled for each platform (because each app install on a device has a different token for push), so you will not be able to use one hub for two Android applications.
In the Android case, you'd want to have one hub per Android app. Then your backend can work with both hubs depending on the scenario. For iOS apps, if they are the same apps but in different platforms as the Android ones, you can do one hub for app 1 for both iOS and Android; then one hub for app 2 for both iOS and Android.
The multi-tenancy feature is for people whose apps are so large they span across multiple hubs. The feature allows customers configure certificates for a whole collection of hubs (which we call a namespace).

Comment: If we have a setup where we do have 2 apps -- A and B, where both have Android and iOS versions (a total of 4 apps) then we need 2 separate Hubs?  If we wish to use PerMessageTelemetry for each app, would that mean we would need 2 separate Standard Tier ($400 USD / month)  hubs?

Comment: Notification Hub Billing is based on namespace (not hub). Hence, you can create two hubs under one standard namespace and PerMessageTelemetry will be enabled on both hubs. But there will be limit on number of device per one standard namespace (10M). Please see this like for more information on billing https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/notification-hubs/